# Unexpected EOF error while parsing?

Tags: python, syntax-error, bots, eof, discord

Never coded in python before but just started and am flat out having errors while creating a discord bot. Not sure what's wrong with the code but it doesn't look like it's the last line.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time

Client = discord.client ()
bot_prefix = "!b"
client = commands.Bot (command_prefix=bot_prefix)

@client.event
async def on_ready () :
    print("With Bepis")     

@client.command(pass_context=true)
async def on_message(ctx:await client.say ("bepis")
                     if message.content == "bepis"
       @client.send_message (message.channel, "**BEPIS**")   

@client.run ("censored token")
```

yes, i know my bot is going to be stupid. I am just using it as a test for a more official bot. Help IS VERY appreciated though.

Comment: can you share the error and traceback?

Comment: The last line is a function decoration with no function. That's not legal, in the same way that a program that just said `2 +` and ended right there wouldn't be legal. But it's at all not clear what you _wanted_ to do there, which makes it very hard to tell you how to fix it without more information.

Comment: Count your parenthesis. There's one missing here: `async def on_message(ctx:await client.say ("bepis")`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the last line to

```
client.run("censored token")
```

The @ specifies a function decorator, so the parser is confused because there is nothing after it. 
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parenthesis next to ("bepis"). Parser finds EOF when it still tries to find the closing parenthesis that's why you get the error.